# jQuery 'Whack-A-Mole'-type game issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a Whack-A-Mole type of game for my Javascript class. I've been trying to figure out how to make it so that the user can only click the "mole" once. As it is right now, I can repeatedly click the "mole" as it fades out. The "moles" are added in dynamically so I couldn't seem to get .one() to work. Hopefully you guys can help me out. The game is almost finished, this is pretty much the last thing I need to change. I've uploaded the game to my website here: http://shawnnance.com/game/

Comment: you should share the related section of your code here

Comment: You could add a `data-clicked` property to an already clicked element and check if it's defined when you click a mole. If it's not defined, increment the score and define the attribute. Otherwise, do nothing.

Comment: if your mole is an object, give it a boolean property `clickedOn` and initialize it as `false`. Put a check in your click function if the property is `false` and only go into the function if its `false`, when someone clicks on it, set the property to `true` and it will not be clicked on again

Comment: In other words: instead of `incrementScore();` inside the `#gamespace` click event, do `if ( $(this).data('clicked') != "yes" ) { $(this).data('clicked', "yes"); incrementScore(); /* other stuff */ } else { /* already clicked, do nothing */ }`

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Alejandro Iván suggests, it's probably better to stick with a data property for this, though using a class would work as well.

## Data Property

Use the `.data()` method to attach arbitary data to your img:

```
$("#gamespace").append('<img src="img/bucket.png" style="top:' + ypos + 'px;left:' + xpos + 'px;"/>').data("clicked","false");
```

Then only track clicks to the unclicked imgs:

```
$('#gamespace img[data-clicked="false"]').on('click', "img", function() {
     incrementScore();
     $(this).data("clicked","true").fadeOut("fast");
     $('#blaster').html("<audio autoplay><source src='img/blaster.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'> Your browser does not support the audio element. </audio>");
});
```

## Class

Add a class to the mole at the start, then only track clicks to that class. For instance:

```
$("#gamespace").append('<img src="img/bucket.png" style="top:' + ypos + 'px;left:' + xpos + 'px;"/>').addClass("notClicked");
```

Then,

```
$('#gamespace img.notClicked').on('click', "img", function() {
     incrementScore();
     $(this).removeClass("notClicked").fadeOut("fast");
     $('#blaster').html("<audio autoplay><source src='img/blaster.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'> Your browser does not support the audio element. </audio>");
});
```

So you remove the class the moment it's been clicked on so it can't be clicked on again.

Comment: This certainly works, but it would be better to use `data` properties. They exist for these kind of uses.

Comment: True, though is there a performance difference between the two?

Comment: It shouldn't be too much, but if there's a difference, defining a class (DOM search, add to class registry, apply styles, events, etc.) should be more power-hungry than just searching the DOM and add a value to an already defined (and stored) object.